# Bonded beast a dragon?

Tags: dnd-5e

So here's the idea...

1. Cast Feeblemind on a dragon.
2. Charm the dragon.
3. Cast Beast Bond on the dragon.

You should in theory have a dragon bonded for at least 30 days

Comment: Hi Flippin Ninjas, you may want to take the [tour].

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to assume you mean the spell Beast Bond, in which case this will not work. Feeblemind on a different beast would work to get around that restriction, but a dragon has a creature type of dragon, not beast. Beast Bond only affects creatures with a creature type of beast.